# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, slf4j

I tried to debug my project but got this

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

what should i do ?

i haven't any dependency for SLF4J in POM just this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

i tried to use the solutions i found in similar posts but didn't solve it !  like

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>logback-classic</groupId>
                <artifactId>ch.qos.logback</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

I tried to replace `provided` to `compile` but didn't solve it too .

I got this with using  `mvn dependency:tree`

```
 org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:provided 
 org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
```

Comment: Okay but to which dependency did you add the exclusions? I would start by running a `mvn dependency:tree` to see if slf4j is being pulled in by other dependencies you have.

Comment: Here <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId> <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId> <version>0.9.6</version> <scope>provided</scope> i edited the post with i got using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @user1 If you solved it, it is SO courtesy to actually provide the solution!

Comment: i did it already !! i accepted the answer that issam wrote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 sources of dependencies for storm one from /usr/local/storm/lib/ directory and the second from maven which cause multiple binding for sl4j.
Try using just one source of dependencies.

Comment: in my case it was the smcf.ear directory in C:\Program Files but similar concept

Answer (score 0):

Following the line of the accepted answer, the way i found to try using just one source of dependencies, was to clone/create again the project i was working on. In my case was an already started project and probably due to poor connection speed, i had a few issues re importing all **Maven Projects**. So i messed up a bit with the project's settings trying to access all the propper dependencies.

That caused some unexpected changes on my project's *pom.xml* file that leaded to the error. So, cloning again de project to a new folder and making the maven re import with some decent internet speed just worked fine for me.
Hope to be helpful. Regards